# Binding of Checkbox to complex type requires implementation of TypeConverter

Tags: razor, blazor-server-side

I have the following problem with my razor page:

I have a view with a checkbox. I bound the checkbox to a bool variable of a complex type "SystemControls"

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="CB_a" @bind="@Combox.Add" />

@code {

SystemControls Combox       = new SystemControls(7, "Combox", false, false);
}
```

SystemControls looks like that:

```
 public class SystemControls: TypeConverter
    {
        public int FkID;
        public string Systemname;
        public bool Add = false;
        public bool Remove = false;

        public SystemControls(int FkID, string Systemname, bool Add, bool Remove)
        {
            this.FkID = FkID;
            this.Systemname = Systemname;
            this.Add = Add;
            this.Remove = Remove;

        }
    }
```

When i start the program, I get the following error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The type
>   'UserManagement.Models.SystemControls' does not have an associated
>   TypeConverter that supports conversion from a string. Apply
>   'TypeConverterAttribute' to the type to register a converter.'

What I understand is that i have to write a converter that converts a string (?) from my checkbox to a bool. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the TypeConverter. Could you guys give me a little hint or can i just cast to bool in the @bind command of the checkbox?